# Azure Table Storage - TableClient not returning ETag

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, etag

Doing some simple queries using `Azure.Data.Table TableClient` and the response is not including the ETag.

My entities inherit `ITableEntity` as required so have the ETag property.

The code is pretty vanilla:

```
        var tableClient = new TableClient(
        new Uri(storageUri),
        tableName,
        new TableSharedKeyCredential(accountName, storageAccountKey));
        
        var response = await tableClient.GetEntityAsync<TEntity>(partitionKey, rowKey);

        return response.Value;
```

The output produced is:

```
{
    "partitionKey": "Partition Key",
    "rowKey": "RowKey",
    "timestamp": "2023-02-07T20:55:45.6532507+00:00",
    "eTag": {},
    "forename": "Forename",
    "surname": "Surname",
    "mobile": "Mobile",
    "address": "Address"
}
```

I'm at a bit of a loss to think what to do as it is all handled within the TableClient so I can't debug all that much.

Any thoughts much appreciated.

********UPDATE********

I have modified the code to run using the type `<TableEntity>` and also for the type `<User>` which is define as:

```
public class User : ITableEntity, IResult
{
    public User() { }
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? Timestamp { get; set; }
    public ETag ETag { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

}
```

The TableClient GetEntityAsync methods are respectivly:

```
 var response = await tableClient.GetEntityAsync<TableEntity>(partitionKey, rowKey);

 var response = await tableClient.GetEntityAsync<User>(partitionKey, rowKey);
```

The first populates all the fields **and** the ETag correctly and the latter just populates all of the other fields **apart from** the ETag.

Dont know if this helps shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi - Updated the question above as I have ben doing a little more testing using TableEntity vs my User entity which inherits form ITableEntity.

Comment: I just ran similar code and the ETag is filled in are you using this package? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Data.Tables/